# Rewrite subdomain

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, subdomain

Obviously a pretty simple question: how do I rewrite

> (value1).example.com/(value2)

to

> /(value1)/(value2)

I've tried a couple of things without success.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond $1/%1 !^([^/]+)/\1$
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)? /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Some explanation: My previous suggestion caused an infinite recursion as the [*L* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) causes a restart of the rewriting process with the new URL:

> Remember, however, that if the `RewriteRule` generates an internal redirect (which frequently occurs when rewriting in a per-directory context), this will reinject the request and will cause processing to be repeated starting from the first `RewriteRule`.

The second condition will avoid this as it compares the subdomain part with the first path segment. And only if they are different the condition is true and the rewrite takes place.

Comment: Hi gumbo, I dont have any changes after writing that on my htaccess. Can you tell me why? I just change the domain, thanks.

Comment: @AnggieAziz Can I tell you why what?